Traefik Let's Encrypt Configuration Conflict with Failover and Weighted Load Balancing
I'm having trouble getting both Let's Encrypt TLS and my custom failover and weighted load balancing configurations to work simultaneously with Traefik.
Problem Description:
When I add the Host rule in the Docker container labels, Let's Encrypt works, but my Traefik YML configurations for failover and weighted load balancing get ignored.
When I remove the Host rule from the container labels, the custom configurations work, but Let's Encrypt fails to issue certificates.
Goal:
To have both Let's Encrypt for TLS and my custom failover and weighted load balancing configurations working together.
Docker compose file
version: '3.8'

networks:
  proxy:
    name: proxy
    driver: bridge

services:
  php-green:
    image: ghcr.io/cloud-castles/cclab-snpv/main/green:latest
    pull_policy: always
    container_name: php-green
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php-green.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php-green.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php-green.rule=Host(`domain.com`)"
    networks:
      - proxy
    depends_on:
      - traefik
      - mariadb

  php-blue:
    image: ghcr.io/cloud-castles/cclab-snpv/main/blue:latest
    pull_policy: always
    container_name: php-blue
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php-blue.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php-blue.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php-blue.rule=Host(`domain.com`)"
    networks:
      - proxy
    depends_on:
      - traefik
      - mariadb

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.11
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.file.directory=/etc/traefik/dynamic/"
      - "--providers.file.watch=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--providers.docker.network=proxy"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      - "--log.level=INFO"
      - "--accesslog=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=mail@hidden.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/acme.json"
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
    environment:
      - TRAEFIK_CERTIFICATESRESOLVERS_LE_ACME_STORAGE=/acme/acme.json
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik/:/etc/traefik/dynamic/
      - acme:/acme
    networks:
      - proxy

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:11.2
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    container_name: mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mariadb
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - proxy
    restart: always

volumes:
  acme:

Dynamic configuration files
Please note they have all been combined into one snippet for easier readability.
# dynamic.yml

http:
  services:
    app:
      weighted:
        services:
          - name: blue
            weight: 50
          - name: green
            weight: 50

    blue:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://php-blue:80"
        
    green:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://php-green:80"


# failover.yml

http:
  services:
    app:
      failover:
        healthCheck: {}
        service: main
        fallback: backup

    main:
      loadBalancer:
        healthCheck:
          path: /health-blue
          interval: 10s
          timeout: 3s
        servers:
          - url: "http://php-blue:80"
        
    backup:
      loadBalancer:
        healthCheck:
          path: /health-green
          interval: 10s
          timeout: 3s
        servers:
          - url: "http://php-green:80"

  routers:
    app-router:
      rule: "Host(`domain.com`)"
      service: "app"
      entryPoints:
        - "web"
        - "websecure"
      tls:
        certresolver: "letsencrypt"
        domains:
          - main: "domain.com"


# traefik.yml

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
  websecure:
    address: ":443"

certificatesResolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    acme:
      email: mail@hidden.com
      storage: "/acme.json"
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: route53
        resolvers:
          - "1.1.1.1:53"
          - "8.8.8.8:53"

Issue
When I include the Host rule in the container labels, Let's Encrypt works but my custom failover and weighted configurations are ignored. If I remove the Host rule, Let's Encrypt fails.
Error
When the Host label is removed:
time="2024-05-31T17:02:22Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from flags."
time="2024-05-31T17:02:22Z" level=info msg="Traefik version 2.11.3 built on 2024-05-21T14:23:18Z"
time="2024-05-31T17:02:25Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"domain.com\"" error="unable to generate a certificate for the domains [domain.com]: acme: error: 429 :: POST :: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:rateLimited :: Error creating new order :: too many certificates (5) already issued for this exact set of domains in the last 168 hours: domain.com, retry after 2024-06-02T01:34:37Z: see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/duplicate-certificate-limit/" routerName=app-router@file rule="Host(`domain.com`)" providerName=letsencrypt.acme ACME CA="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
time="2024-05-31T17:02:25Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"php-blue-domain\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [php-blue-domain]: acme: error: 400 :: POST :: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:rejectedIdentifier :: Error creating new order :: Cannot issue for \"php-blue-domain\": Domain name needs at least one dot" providerName=letsencrypt.acme ACME CA="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" routerName=php-blue-http@docker rule="Host(`php-blue-domain`)"
time="2024-05-31T17:02:25Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"php-green-domain\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [php-green-domain]: acme: error: 400 :: POST :: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:rejectedIdentifier :: Error creating new order :: Cannot issue for \"php-green-domain\": Domain name needs at least one dot" rule="Host(`php-green-domain`)" providerName=letsencrypt.acme ACME CA="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" routerName=php-green-http@docker


How can I achieve this configuration in Traefik?

I managed to get it done by switching to DNS Challenge instead of HTTP .. i'll anwser the question with the updated YML.
